# url rewrite with connect history api fallback

Tags: javascript, regex, url-rewriting, html5-history

I am using this library to do my URL fallback to index.html on my javascript single page application: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

This library works well for routes such as below:

mysite.com
mysite.com/foo
mysite.com/bar

However, it seems I have to customize the rewrite method to handler URLS such as:

mysite.com/foo/bar

I've already raised an [issue](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback/issues/16) on github and got some feedback from the author but I can't really get this working as my regex skills is absolutely [shiz](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shiz&defid=2724751).

**UPDATE 1 (2016-01-13 15:27):**

Example of the rewrite rules I have below. As you can see, I am being quite repetitive with these rules as I have them for every single route that such as mysite.com/bar or mysite.com/foo. What's even worse, this won't handle the scenario where I have mysite.com/{foo}/edit where foo is a variable obviously:

```
            from: /^\/foo\/css\/.*$/,
            to: function (context) {
                return context.parsedUrl.pathname.replace('/foo', '');
            }
        },
        {
            from: /^\/bar\/js\/.*$/,
            to: function (context) {
                return context.parsedUrl.pathname.replace('/bar', '');
            }
        },
```

Comment: Why the downvote so I can improve this?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote but also not sure how we can help you since there is no regex or code in your question that we can help you fix.

Comment: @anubhava I added the code example. Sorry, completely missed that!

Comment: But these 2 snippets are for `tracks/css` and `tracks/js` only. How is this handling `/foo` or `/bar`?

Comment: /foo and /bar were only hypothetical examples ... updated the code to make it clear.

Comment: I have the exact same problem like you on a vuejs website. After I add the "connect-history-api-fallback", it still would not let me access url like "/foo/bar" in the godaddy server. What should I do @AndreGallo

Answer (score 0):

I've found out today that there was nothing wrong with the connect history api fallback. I just had the wrong URL paths in both my index.html file and also on my requirejs' baseUrl configuration. Answers to this questions led me to my conclusion: [mod_rewrite to index.html breaks relative paths for deep URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865480/mod-rewrite-to-index-html-breaks-relative-paths-for-deep-urls)