# browser-sync not working with single page application

Tags: single-page-application, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I have a single page application that does not use hash URLs I want to use the history API. I am using the middleware historyApiFallback() in browserSync server options. However, this is only working for one level deep URLs:

http://localhost:3000/main correctly resolves to index.html
BUT
http://localhost:3000/main/a is NOT working. The browser shows "connected to browser sync" and then a blank page is displayed.

Anyone knows what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the URLs for js and css resources weren't correctly setup. This post helped me fixed the issue: [mod_rewrite to index.html breaks relative paths for deep URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865480/mod-rewrite-to-index-html-breaks-relative-paths-for-deep-urls)